# How to display Date in ListBox

Tags: sqlite, winrt-xaml

I have databinded the listBox with data from Sqlite DB but the date show as dd/mm/yyyy hhmmss am/pm.  How to I convert the date for the below Listbox. I want a few choice of date format:

1) DD/MM/YYYY ( ie : 1/10/2013)

2) DD/MM ( ie : 1 Oct )

3) DD/Month/YYYY ( ie 1 Oct 2013)

Thanks.

```
<ListBox  HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="Transparent"  Background="White"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="listBox1" Width="550"  Height="350">

  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>

        <Grid Width="650" Background="White">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
               </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="30">
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="100">
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="50">
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="150">

                      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

       <TextBlock Margin="1,3,0,0" FontSize="23" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="DarkBlue" Text="{Binding CustId}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />

       <TextBlock Margin="10,3,0,0" FontSize="23" Foreground="DarkBlue" Text="{Binding No}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="1" />

      <TextBlock Margin="10,3,0,0" FontSize="23" Foreground="DarkBlue" Text="{Binding Document}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />

       <TextBlock Margin="50,3,0,0" FontSize="23" Foreground="DarkBlue" Text="{Binding Order_Date}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" />                           


        </Grid>

    </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically in XAML you'd use the `StringFormat` binding expression.  This is not present in Windows 8.  Most people use a BindingConverter for this.  A quick google search turned up this, which should work for you.

http://www.ricky-dev.com/2012/08/stringformat-missing-from-binding-expressions-in-winrt/

or

http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2012/03/19/A-StringFormat-converter-for-Windows-8-Metro.aspx